# Cannot work api request in Spring Cloud API Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a problem about running the URLs shown below.

```
http://localhost:8041/users-ws/users/status/check (run)
http://localhost:8041/users/status/check (not run)
```

What I want to do is to run all these URL but only the first one runs.
How can I run both URLs?
How can I revise application properties file?

Here is my code snippet shown below in application.properties file in Spring Cloud API Gateway

```
server.port=8041
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8040/eureka

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your user-ws controller?
Anyway, try that:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users/**
```

looks like your application name is "users-ws", and your request mapping is "/users", in this case, is not necessary put your application name in the path but we need to see more code, to be honest.